# How to check if strings match in C#

Tags: c#, string, md5, matching

I'm am trying to create a program where the user inputs two MD5 hashes and then clicks a button to verify whether they match. I tried the following but it always returns the `else`:

```
    // I skiped the Initialize Component() block for this post.

    private void verifyButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textHash1 == textHash2)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The hashes match");
        }

        else MessageBox.Show("The hashes do not match");
    }
```

This code always return the else statement

Comment: I hope I gave as much information needed, I'm new here.

Comment: What are `textHash1` and `textHash2`? Strings or textboxes?

Comment: Your code is correct, data is not. Please post code related to comparison only (i.e. `string s1= "abc"; string s2="abd"; if (s1 == s2)...` ). Right now it is very unclear what types of `textHash1` is (most likely `TextBox` which explains why 2 TB are not equal all the time).

Comment: textHash1 and textHash2 are Text Boxes. Sorry for not mentioning that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `textHash1` and `textHash2` are textboxes.. this won't work:

```
if (textHash1 == textHash2)
```

That is because you're comparing controls.. they are completely different controls (both textboxes yes.. but different references).

You want to compare their `Text` properties:

```
if (textHash1.Text == textHash2.Text)
```

Comment: Is this a good way to verify if the MD5s match, or is there a better way?

Comment: This is a straight up string comparison. If it doesn't matter whether the hash is uppercased or lowercased then you can force them upper/lower and compare.. like this: `if (textHash1.Text.ToUpper() == textHash2.Text.ToUpper())`.